# Why is it bad to create an ArrayList of all the objects of a class as a class variable?

Tags: java, arraylist

So my only thought for why this might be the case is that each object of that class created carries it with it an identical array list so it's a bad use of memory?

Comment: What does it mean "all the objects of a class" ? could you post an example ?

Comment: Also, static fields only take up memory once - they are not duplicated for each object of the class. There would thus only be one copy of the list.

Comment: @FrançoisLEPORCQ so if for instance I had a class Dog and used it to make individual dog objects. Sorry I will try to post an example when I get home

Comment: You want to keep this objects list in memory ? you could do that with a static modifier on your list, for me in absolute is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with your reasoning. It isn't bad if you have only a few instances of a class, but as you create more and more, the total amount of arrayList elements increases exponentially. Plus, adding more elements to an arrayList is extremely expensive (because the implementation involves creating an entirely new array with more elements). So imagine how slow it would be to add 1 more element to 100 arrayLists with 100 elements each. It's pretty inefficient, and I would rather have an arrayList of all the instances of a particular class as a variable outside of the class and just pass in the arrayList as a parameter.